# Why are subscribed podcasts appearing more than once on my iPod touch 5g?

Tags: ipod-touch, podcasts.app

After c. 5 years, I 'upgraded' from a 3g touch to a 5g model. I soon noticed that the list of podcasts shown on the iPod was getting longer and longer. There were at least 3 copies of each podcast source in the list.

I'm on iOS 8.4.1 and I just deleted all the podcasts from the iPod and then also from my iTunes and resubscribed to the podcasts I regularly hear.

It's only been a few days but the iPod now shows 2 copies of each subscribed podcast.

Is there anyone who can explain to a simple software engineer what I might be doing wrong? After all I'm not new to the iPod but I cannot figure out what's going wrong here.

Comment: What version of iOS are you running? That establishes the version of the podcast app for us.

Comment: @bmike - don't have it with me at the moment. I bought it about 3 weeks ago and updated the OS almost immediately. I'll add the exact version nr this evening...

Comment: @Mark if you reproduced this on iOS 8 please flag as a duplicate.

Comment: @bmike I can't close as dup as there is no accepted answer (and I should not answer due to NDA and the probabilty of it changing before release)

Comment: @Mark - you seem like you're in the know. How do you work around this issue? I only really use the iPod for podcasts and the current handling sucks. Do I have to remove all podcasts from the device before syncing? :-/

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with multiple copies podcasts on iOS 8.

<s>The new version on iOS 9 seems to have fixed this if you also make sure the podcast is subscribed on both iOS and iTunes.</s>

The alternative is downcast to old iOS which had podcasts as part of Music as that worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I took the upgrade to iOS 9 and the podcasts function much better than iOS 8. I'm not thrilled about the new layout etc but at least each podcast only appears once.

Comment: @paul - it has got worse for me now which is why I struckout the answer